# Border around a group of elements floated left?

Tags: css

I have a container div with several items within it. The container needs to have a border. The problem is I also need to have those elements floated left within the container, and that seems to "remove" the elements from the flow.

When I try to add a border to the container, it doesn't go around all the elements, as if they are not within the container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
</div>

.one {
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}

.container {
    width:350px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:black;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ynwbzw97/

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to clear your floats to keep them inside the container div.

Just add a div with clear:both after the last inner div and before the final /div tag.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

So your full markup would be:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, floated elements are removed from the flow. Since the `.container` element *only* contains floated elements, it essentially collapses upon itself. Therefore you need to [clear the floated elements](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Either change the `overflow` of the `.container` element to soemthing other than `visible` in order to establish a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wxn0bq9/)

```
.container {
    width: 350px;
    overflow: auto;     /* added.. */
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

---

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9za6u3x/)

or use a pseudo-element clearfix:

```
.container:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple hack with you class

```
.one{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Adding a child div in the last with the style `clear:both` is very decent solution.